# XF86-video-intel vs Modesetting for a 2nd Monitor [Manjaro]

Tags: x11, drivers, manjaro, display, intel

I am trying to get an external monitor (Dell) working on my laptop (dell) via a ubc-c docking station (dell). and I am having some issue - Running on an up to date Manjaro (5.4.28-1)

Basically while in KDE, the 2nd monitor is detected correctly and signal is going, but I have no image. I can't figure out what is going on. If move to a tty (ctrl+alt+F2) the second screen comes to life. 
If I boot on my win session (same laptop) all is working good.

I have tryied the xf86-video-intel driver, but it is just broken. KDE is unsuable so I had to revert back to modeseting.

Any suggestion most welcome.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in desperation I wiped the system and went for a kubuntu 20.04 - I have a dell dev edition so I thought that might help. It did initialy, but after few update it stopped working again.

So that made me start looking in KDE. and I finally found it.

Appenrently, something, I don't know if it is the laptop, the screen or the docking station doesn't like OpenGL. 
By changing the rendering to something else that openGL it worked just fine. So I am assuming it would be the same fix in Manjaro.

For the time Beeing I am happy in Kubuntu - Much better battery life ;)

I hope that can be uselfull to somebody.